# Linking twitter to facebook page

Tags: facebook, twitter

I just created a page on FB as of August 1st 2012, and I am constantly getting this error as I am trying to link my twitter account to the facebook page.

> "ERROR:This endpoint has been deprecated.To temporarily reenable
>   it,you may disable the "august_2012" platform migration. It will be
>   disable permanently on August 1,2012."

Comment: As the error states, what you are trying to achieve has been deprecated by the facebook api. You will need to find another solution.

Comment: I am trying to get all my tweets to show up on the facebook page every time i tweet, but unfortunately i am getting the error. hope this helps clarify something things.

Comment: try [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

It's a twitter issue. The twitter app for facebook has not been updated to the new iFrames framework, and still relies on the FBML framework. Thus we'll have to wait till the app is updated. The solution provided above only works if the developer of twitter app enables that option. You can read more here:
http://technoritz.com/post/28770685151/this-is-not-a-facebook-problem-it-is-a-twitter

Here is the official response from twitter:
https://twitter.com/Support/statuses/231138059071156225

Answer (score 0):

Try https://twitter.com/settings/profile
or
https://www.facebook.com/twitter/

Comment: Why should these links be an answer if Alexander already visited them (i'm sure he did, by the fact that i have the same problem!)

Answer (score 0):

"Some users are reporting problems connecting their Twitter account to a Facebook page. Our engineers are investigating." From the Twitter @Support. I have the same error